# Undefined control sequence. <argument> \sevrm \endpicture}

Tags: latex-2.09

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,doublespace,blind,pictex}
%\documentstyle[11pt,doublespace,blind,pictex]{article}
% for use with LaTeX, comment out the following lines
%\font\sevrm=cmr7
%\font\twltt=cmtt12
%\def\mbox=\relax
%\font\sixtt=cmr6
%\font\sixtt=cmtt8

% constants
\let\pics=2
\let\dottedpics=1
\let\nopics=0

% commands to change picture drawing mode
\newcommand{\nopictures}{\let\picturemode=\nopics}
\newcommand{\dottedpictures}{\let\picturemode=\dottedpics}
\newcommand{\pictures}{\let\picturemode=\pics}

% set default
\pictures
\textwidth 15.5cm
\textheight 21.7cm
\voffset=-2.7cm
\hoffset=-9.5mm
\setstretch{2.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\mbox{\beginpicture
\setcoordinatesystem units < 1.000in, 1.000in>
\unitlength= 1.000in
\linethickness=0.7pt
\setplotsymbol ({\sevrm .})
\setlinear
\if \picturemode \nopics \else
\if \picturemode \dottedpics \setdots \fi
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.487  7.763 to  3.737  7.763
\putrule from  3.737  7.763 to  3.737  7.013
\putrule from  3.737  7.013 to  2.487  7.013
\putrule from  2.487  7.013 to  2.487  7.763
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\setdashes < 0.0500in>
\plot  4.238  6.763  4.113  7.450 /
%
% arrow head
%
\setsolid
\plot  4.155  7.356  4.113  7.450  4.106  7.347 /
%
\setdashes < 0.0500in>
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  4.238  9.512  4.113  8.825 /
%
% arrow head
%
\setsolid
\plot  4.106  8.928  4.113  8.825  4.155  8.919 /
%
\setdashes < 0.0500in>
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\setsolid
\putrule from  4.363  8.762 to  5.113  8.762
\putrule from  5.113  8.762 to  5.113  7.513
\putrule from  5.113  7.513 to  4.363  7.513
\putrule from  4.363  7.513 to  4.363  8.762
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  5.113  8.137 to  5.738  8.137
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  5.638  8.113  5.738  8.137  5.638  8.162 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  3.737  7.388  4.363  7.825 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  4.295  7.747  4.363  7.825  4.266  7.788 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  3.737  8.950  4.363  8.450 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  4.269  8.493  4.363  8.450  4.300  8.532 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  1.487  8.137  2.487  7.388 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.392  7.427  2.487  7.388  2.422  7.467 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  1.487  8.137  2.487  8.887 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.422  8.808  2.487  8.887  2.392  8.848 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  0.488  8.137 to  1.487  8.137
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  1.387  8.113  1.487  8.137  1.387  8.162 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.487  7.763 to  3.737  7.763
\putrule from  3.737  7.763 to  3.737  7.013
\putrule from  3.737  7.013 to  2.487  7.013
\putrule from  2.487  7.013 to  2.487  7.763
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.487  9.262 to  3.737  9.262
\putrule from  3.737  9.262 to  3.737  8.512
\putrule from  3.737  8.512 to  2.487  8.512
\putrule from  2.487  8.512 to  2.487  9.262
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  7.075 to  2.737  7.200
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.763  7.100  2.737  7.200  2.712  7.100 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.612  7.513 to  3.112  7.513
\putrule from  3.112  7.513 to  3.112  7.263
\putrule from  3.112  7.263 to  2.612  7.263
\putrule from  2.612  7.263 to  2.612  7.513
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  6.513 to  2.737  6.888
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.763  6.788  2.737  6.888  2.712  6.788 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  9.762 to  2.737  9.387
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.712  9.488  2.737  9.387  2.763  9.488 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.612  9.012 to  3.112  9.012
\putrule from  3.112  9.012 to  3.112  8.762
\putrule from  3.112  8.762 to  2.612  8.762
\putrule from  2.612  8.762 to  2.612  9.012
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  9.200 to  2.737  9.075
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.712  9.175  2.737  9.075  2.763  9.175 /
%
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt PARTIAL RESULT 1} [lB] at  4.300  6.700
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt PARTIAL RESULT 2} [lB] at  4.300  9.450
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt M} [lB] at  5.238  8.200
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt C} [lB] at  0.800  8.200
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\tentt MOD. SHADOW} [lB] at  2.862  7.075
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt SHADOW 1} [lB] at  2.987  6.575
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt SHADOW 2 } [lB] at  2.987  9.575
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\tentt MOD. SHADOW} [lB] at  2.862  9.075
\fi
\linethickness=0pt
\putrectangle corners at  0.488  9.762 and  5.738  6.513
\endpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: File `doublespace.sty' not found`. See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doublespace: **This pack­age should no longer be used: it has se­ri­ous bugs, and is no longer main­tained. It is su­per­seded by setspace.**  Could you please make your **code minimal**: The minimal code required in order to reproduce your error?

Comment: Well, can't you uncomment a few lines?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Mybe he's a Captain America kind of guy -- frozen in ice for decades and now freshly awoken :).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have written few papers which were written years ago and I am kind of converting them to new latex version...

Comment: but this isn't converting them it's just making some weird hybrid but thanks for the explanation! From your questions it seemed like you were a new latex user who had somehow come across 30 year old example files, in which case the answer would be **don't do that**. If they are your files, then obviously that answer is not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,pictex,setspace}
%\documentstyle[11pt,doublespace,blind,pictex]{article}
% for use with LaTeX, comment out the following lines
\font\sevrm=cmr7
\font\nintt=cmtt9
\font\tentt=cmtt10
%\font\twltt=cmtt12
%\def\mbox=\relax
%\font\sixtt=cmr6
%\font\sixtt=cmtt8

% constants
\let\pics=2
\let\dottedpics=1
\let\nopics=0

% commands to change picture drawing mode
\newcommand{\nopictures}{\let\picturemode=\nopics}
\newcommand{\dottedpictures}{\let\picturemode=\dottedpics}
\newcommand{\pictures}{\let\picturemode=\pics}

% set default
\pictures
\textwidth 15.5cm
\textheight 21.7cm
\voffset=-2.7cm
\hoffset=-9.5mm
\setstretch{2.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\mbox{\beginpicture
\setcoordinatesystem units < 1.000in, 1.000in>
\unitlength= 1.000in
\linethickness=0.7pt
\setplotsymbol ({\sevrm .})
\setlinear
\if \picturemode \nopics \else
\if \picturemode \dottedpics \setdots \fi
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.487  7.763 to  3.737  7.763
\putrule from  3.737  7.763 to  3.737  7.013
\putrule from  3.737  7.013 to  2.487  7.013
\putrule from  2.487  7.013 to  2.487  7.763
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\setdashes < 0.0500in>
\plot  4.238  6.763  4.113  7.450 /
%
% arrow head
%
\setsolid
\plot  4.155  7.356  4.113  7.450  4.106  7.347 /
%
\setdashes < 0.0500in>
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  4.238  9.512  4.113  8.825 /
%
% arrow head
%
\setsolid
\plot  4.106  8.928  4.113  8.825  4.155  8.919 /
%
\setdashes < 0.0500in>
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\setsolid
\putrule from  4.363  8.762 to  5.113  8.762
\putrule from  5.113  8.762 to  5.113  7.513
\putrule from  5.113  7.513 to  4.363  7.513
\putrule from  4.363  7.513 to  4.363  8.762
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  5.113  8.137 to  5.738  8.137
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  5.638  8.113  5.738  8.137  5.638  8.162 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  3.737  7.388  4.363  7.825 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  4.295  7.747  4.363  7.825  4.266  7.788 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  3.737  8.950  4.363  8.450 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  4.269  8.493  4.363  8.450  4.300  8.532 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  1.487  8.137  2.487  7.388 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.392  7.427  2.487  7.388  2.422  7.467 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\plot  1.487  8.137  2.487  8.887 /
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.422  8.808  2.487  8.887  2.392  8.848 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  0.488  8.137 to  1.487  8.137
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  1.387  8.113  1.487  8.137  1.387  8.162 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.487  7.763 to  3.737  7.763
\putrule from  3.737  7.763 to  3.737  7.013
\putrule from  3.737  7.013 to  2.487  7.013
\putrule from  2.487  7.013 to  2.487  7.763
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.487  9.262 to  3.737  9.262
\putrule from  3.737  9.262 to  3.737  8.512
\putrule from  3.737  8.512 to  2.487  8.512
\putrule from  2.487  8.512 to  2.487  9.262
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  7.075 to  2.737  7.200
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.763  7.100  2.737  7.200  2.712  7.100 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.612  7.513 to  3.112  7.513
\putrule from  3.112  7.513 to  3.112  7.263
\putrule from  3.112  7.263 to  2.612  7.263
\putrule from  2.612  7.263 to  2.612  7.513
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  6.513 to  2.737  6.888
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.763  6.788  2.737  6.888  2.712  6.788 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  9.762 to  2.737  9.387
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.712  9.488  2.737  9.387  2.763  9.488 /
%
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.612  9.012 to  3.112  9.012
\putrule from  3.112  9.012 to  3.112  8.762
\putrule from  3.112  8.762 to  2.612  8.762
\putrule from  2.612  8.762 to  2.612  9.012
%
% Fig POLYLINE object
%
\putrule from  2.737  9.200 to  2.737  9.075
%
% arrow head
%
\plot  2.712  9.175  2.737  9.075  2.763  9.175 /
%
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt PARTIAL RESULT 1} [lB] at  4.300  6.700
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt PARTIAL RESULT 2} [lB] at  4.300  9.450
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt M} [lB] at  5.238  8.200
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt C} [lB] at  0.800  8.200
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\tentt MOD. SHADOW} [lB] at  2.862  7.075
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt SHADOW 1} [lB] at  2.987  6.575
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\nintt SHADOW 2 } [lB] at  2.987  9.575
%
% Fig TEXT object
%
\put {\tentt MOD. SHADOW} [lB] at  2.862  9.075
\fi
\linethickness=0pt
\putrectangle corners at  0.488  9.762 and  5.738  6.513
\endpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a really old schematic produced with a typewriter and a ruler and pencil :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, but in the 80's there was not much more.